# Passing python array to a c function using c_types

Tags: c++, python, c

I have a wrapper function in C library that interacts with the some python scripts.

```
int func(uint8_t *_data, int _len);
```

I want to pass a array or list in python to this function.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to create a C array type is to use the multiplication operator on the appropriate type in `ctypes`, which automatically generates a new type object. For example...

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> ctypes.c_ubyte * 3
<class '__main__.c_ubyte_Array_3'>
```

...which can be constructed with the same number of arguments...

```
>>> (ctypes.c_ubyte * 3)(0, 1, 2)
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_3 object at 0x7fe51e0fa710>
```

...or you can use the `*` operator to call it with the contents of a list...

```
>>> (ctypes.c_ubyte * 3)(*range(3))
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_3 object at 0x7fe51e0fa7a0>
```

...so you'd need something like...

```
import ctypes

my_c_library = ctypes.CDLL('my_c_library.dll')

def call_my_func(input_list):
    length = len(input_list)
    array = (ctypes.c_ubyte * length)(*input_list)
    return my_c_library.func(array, length)

my_list = [0, 1, 2]
print call_my_func(my_list)
```